# Making a shoppingcart

Tags: javascript, html, css

First things first: English is not my first language and there might be flaws in my topics. My apologies for that ;)

Anyways, for a school project I have to make a webshop using javascript. Now I'm pretty new to javascript so I know vaguely what I should do, but not exactly.
I put five products in a table, as well as their prices and five buttons, for each product one button.
I reserved the right half of the page for the actual shopping cart, where the ordered products should be listed after I clicked the button belonging to that product.

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webshop</title>
<style>
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    button {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    table {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
    }

    p {
        padding: 5px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #shoppingCartDiv {
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 780px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 98%;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>&euro; 15</td>
            <td><button id="button1" type="button" onClick(addToCart)>Add to cart</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>&euro; 30</td>
            <td><button id="button2" type="button" onClick(addToCart)>Add to cart</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 3</td>
            <td>&euro; 45</td>
            <td><button id="button3" type="button" onClick(addToCart)>Add to cart</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 4</td>
            <td>&euro; 60</td>
            <td><button id="button4" type="button" onClick(addToCart)>Add to cart</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 5</td>
            <td>&euro; 75</td>
            <td><button id="button5" type="button" onClick(addToCart)>Add to cart</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="shoppingCartDiv">
        <p id="shoppingCartP">
            <i>Your shopping cart is empty</i>
        </p>
    </div>
<script>
    var shoppingCart;

    function addToCart(button) {
        var button = button.id;
        switch (button) {
            case "button1":
                if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                    shoppingCartP = "Product 1" + "<br />"
                } else {
                    (shoppingCartP = shoppingCartP + "Product 1" + "<br />")
                    }
        }

        document.getElementById("shoppingCartP").innerHTML = shoppingCart;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you might suspect, I don't exactly know how to use functions.
Also I'm having some trouble with assigning the button to the right product.

Thanks in advance :)
Thomas.

Comment: `onClick(addToCart)` should be `onclick="addToCart()"`

Comment: Oh right lol that's quite a rookie mistake xD thanks

It still does not work though, just nothing is happening when I hit the button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Webshop</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
        body {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    
        button {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    
        table {
            float: left;
            width: 40%;
        }
    
        p {
            padding: 5px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    
        #shoppingCartDiv {
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            left: 780px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 98%;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td>&euro; 15</td>
                <td><button id="button1" type="button" onClick="addToCart(this.id);">Add to cart</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 2</td>
                <td>&euro; 30</td>
                <td><button id="button2" type="button" onClick="addToCart(this.id);">Add to cart</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 3</td>
                <td>&euro; 45</td>
                <td><button id="button3" type="button" onClick="addToCart(this.id);">Add to cart</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 4</td>
                <td>&euro; 60</td>
                <td><button id="button4" type="button" onClick="addToCart(this.id);">Add to cart</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 5</td>
                <td>&euro; 75</td>
                <td><button id="button5" type="button" onClick="addToCart(this.id);">Add to cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <div id="shoppingCartDiv">
            <p id="shoppingCartP">
            </p>
        </div>
    <script>
    window.onload=function()
    {
     document.getElementById("shoppingCartP").innerHTML = "Your shopping cart is empty";
    }
        var shoppingCart;
        function addToCart(id) {
            var id=id;
       shoppingCartP=document.getElementById("shoppingCartP").innerHTML;
            switch (id) {
                case "button1" :
                    if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                        shoppingCart = "Product 1" + "<br>"
                    } 
        else if (shoppingCartP.indexOf("Product 1")>-1){
        }
        else {
                        (shoppingCart= shoppingCartP + "Product 1" + "<br>")
                        }
         break;
          case "button2":
                    if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                        shoppingCart= "Product 2" + "<br />"
                    }
        else if (shoppingCartP.indexOf("Product 2")>-1){
        }
        else {
                        (shoppingCart = shoppingCartP + "Product 2" + "<br />")
                        }
         break;
          case "button3":
                    if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                        shoppingCart = "Product 3" + "<br />"
                    } 
        else if (shoppingCartP.indexOf("Product 3")>-1){
        }
        else {
                        (shoppingCart = shoppingCartP + "Product 3" + "<br />")
                        }
         break;
          case "button4":
                    if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                        shoppingCart = "Product 4" + "<br />"
                    } 
        else if (shoppingCartP.indexOf("Product 4")>-1){
        }
        else {
                        (shoppingCart = shoppingCartP + "Product 4" + "<br />")
                        }
         break;
          case "button5":
                    if (shoppingCartP == "Your shopping cart is empty") {
                        shoppingCart = "Product 5" + "<br />"
                    } 
        else if (shoppingCartP.indexOf("Product 5")>-1){
        }
        else {
                        (shoppingCart = shoppingCartP + "Product 5" + "<br />")
                        }
         break;
            }
    
            document.getElementById("shoppingCartP").innerHTML = shoppingCart;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an **[event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)** for all `buttons` and for your paragraph `p` for displaying the product(s) in the shopping cart.

For all `Buttons` example:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = addToCart;
}
```

For a `paragraph` example:

```
var para = document.querySelector('p');
```

For checking if the cart is empty, try `indexOf()` [string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods).

```
if(para.innerHTML.indexOf('empty')>0) {
   para.innerHTML = ""; // clear the shopping cart first
 }
 para.innerHTML += "Product 1 <br />";
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your response :)
But are there no other ways to do it? Because I did not learn the part with the querySelector and I suppose I'll have to work with what I already learned (or I simply missed something lol)

Comment: @ThomasKuijpers you can individually set each button by using `getElementById` then `button<number>.onclick = addToCart;`